# Strange use of const - why does this compile?

Tags: c++, gcc

I recently found the following function definition in some code I was reviewing:

```
void func( const::std::string& str )
{
    // Do something...
}
```

I am surprised that the `const::std::string` appears to be legal ( it compiles with GCC4.4, GCC 4.8, Clang 3.2 & Intel 13.0.1).

Does the standard specify that `const` can be used as a `namespace`?

Comment: Are you sure, it's not `const ::std::string...` (note the space)?

Comment: @KirilKirov And what difference does the space make?  The sequence of tokens is indentical, with or without the space.

Comment: @JamesKanze: it's the space operator. oh well one day late. but anyway.

Comment: If you're reviewing... I'd still ask for it to be changed.  `::std::string const&` would be far better, and the leading `::` is not really idiomatic either---one supposes (hopes) that there will be no symbol `std` outside of the standard library which might require the disabiguization.

Comment: @Alf Don't laugh.  I've been using Mathematica recently, and in Mathematica, the space _is_ an operator.  (It's a way of writing multiplication.)

Comment: I'll definitely add `const::std::string` to my repertoire - thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: @KerrekSB: while the `const::std::string` is almost of the same clarity as the goes-down-to operator `-->` and the automatic URL `http://www.google.com`, i personally favor writing pi in Norwegian notation, `x = 3,14;`. for those occasions where cuteness of code should be accentuated. of course.

Comment: The missing space completely threw me - to me `const ::std::string` and `const::std::string` look like completely different pieces of code, I did not realise that the lack of a space had no affect on the way the code is parsed!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does the standard specify that const can be used as a namespace?

No, it does not, because it can't be.

Your code is the same as:

```
void func( const ::std::string& str );
```

The first scope resolution operator denotes global namespace.

Answer (score 6):

It is parsed as

```
const ::std::string& str
```

where `::std::string` is a valid way to refer to `std::string`.

Answer (score 4):

This compiles because the syntax is evaluated as:

```
void func( const ::std::string& str )
```

Which means that `std` is declared in global scope. In this context an extra `::` before `std` is redundant to mention.

Comment: "In this context"?  What do we know about the context.  Maybe this is in something like `namespace Mine { namespace std { ... } }`.  (Not that I think it likely.  And any programmer who defines a nested namespace with the name `std` deserves to be shot.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, "in this context" ... I used these words because, it's quite evident that the code would have an `#include<string>` and the code is compiling fine. So we don't need an explicit global scope `::` here. We can nest `std` inside any other namespace, but in that case the code will not compile (unless `using namespace Mine;`).